# Angular 2+ , material not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

when I install **npm install --save @angular/material**

It gives me following response :

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

But this above one are just warnings , but when I try to actually import it in app.module.ts **npm start** breaks as follows:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: tsc -p src/
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script 'tsc -p src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! tsc -p src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! E:\My Projects\angular-quickstart-master\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: npm run build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! E:\My Projects\angular-quickstart-master\npm-debug.log
```

I am not sure what is the exact issue. Can any one please help.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the node_modules folder and ran "npm install" command?? which version of npm is on your machine?

Comment: its 3.10.10 and node version is 6.10.0

Comment: I would upgrade my node and npm globally and then delete the node_modules folder in my project and then re-install all the dependencies. I have similar issue couple of weeks ago and it got resolved by this approach. Currently, I'm on node: v6.10.3 and npm: 5.0.3

Comment: I tried doing it but still it didnt work. So should I upgrade my npm version ?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt by upgrading the npm. I just created a new project with angular-cli and added angular/material which is "@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.6". It has strong peer dependencies on angular/core and angular/common. The versioning of those peer dependencies might be a reason.? Not sure.... Could you please share your package.json to have a final look.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  }

Comment: I have just added dependencies and devDependencies due to limitation of the characters

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new angular project using the package.json you have provided and everything is working great. Upgrading the node/npm is the way, I feel.

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  }`

[image]

Comment: So could you import material and use it in your app ?